# Confused about this use of a lambda

Tags: haskell

So I think of Lambdas as demonstrated in Learn You a Haskell:

```
(filter (\xs -> length xs > 15) (map chain [1..100]))
```

The input for xs is the list generated from `(map chain [1..100]))`
That's easy enough to read.

So here's where I get confused, looking at some Real World Code (tm).

Here's a function from
[conduit](https://github.com/snoyberg/conduit/blob/master/resourcet/Control/Monad/Trans/Resource.hs)

```
fmap f (ResourceT m) = ResourceT $ \r -> fmap f (m r)
```

Where is the input for r coming from?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`r` won't have a value until the function `\r -> fmap f (m r)` is actually called. In the definition of `fmap`, the function is never called - it's only stored in a `ResourceT`. It can then later be taken out of the `ResourceT` and called. That's when `r` will get a value.

Answer (score 5):

The `\r -> fmap f (m r)` is a function which is an example of a [closure](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Closure). The variables `f` and `m` are part of the environment where the function is going to be executed. Also since Haskell is a functional language functions could be passed around without being evaluated or being partially evaluated like in this case.